# Tables alignment anomaly

Tags: html, html-table

I'm creating a simple newsletter so I decide to use a 700px wide table and to stop the top section of my table from messing up I created another table underneath it with the same width (700px). For some reason the top half has changed to 705px while playing about with TD's and if I set it back to 700px it's too narrow, even though the table underneath is 700px wide.

You can see the width change on the the grey box:

```
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th height="19" colspan="6" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height="130" colspan="2" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" scope="row"><img src="sides_wider.png" width="63" height="1" /></th>
    <th width="345" height="130" align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" scope="row"><img src="logo.png" width="200" height="100" align="bottom" /></th>
    <th width="221" height="130" align="right" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" scope="row">Newsletter #1 - <strong>05.08.13</strong>
    <th width="63" height="130" colspan="2" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" scope="row"><img src="sides_wider.png" width="63" height="1" /></th>
</tr>
</table>


<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th height="2" colspan="6" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" scope="row"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="50" height="47" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" scope="row"><img src="sides.png" width="50" height="1" /></th>
    <th colspan="4" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><img src="banner.png" width="600" height="200" /></th>
    <th width="50" bgcolor="#E9E9E9"><img src="sides.png" width="50" height="1" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="50" height="79" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    <th  width="50" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="50" height="147" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="35" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="196" height="40" bgcolor="#F3F3F3" style="padding:15px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor accusata duo ut. </th>
    <th width="330" height="40" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="padding:15px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor accusata duo ut. </th>
    <th width="33" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="50" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th bgcolor="#F3F3F3" height="40" style="padding:15px; border-top: solid 1px #CCC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor accusata duo ut. </th>
    <th width="330" height="40" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="padding:15px; border-top: solid 1px #CCC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor accusata duo ut. </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th height="16" colspan="6" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like there's things going wrong in your markup. You open <td> tags and close them with <th>. You also open a <tr> and don't close it. These things will mess up your layout.

Comment: Heres a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGB4k/

Comment: @Coop Oh I see, the problem is I change my <th> to <td> because the text always centers and goes bold otherwise. I there a way around that without changing it to <td>?

Comment: You can style the <th> with CSS or inline styling. Set them to text-align:left; and font-weight:normal;

Comment: @much obliged! I'll give that a shot

Comment: Still got a problem with the width: http://jsfiddle.net/mGB4k/1/

Comment: I don't understand well what you want to do...do you need to have two nested tables? What do you mean with "to stop the top section of my table from messing up"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Although the `<td>` and `<th>` issue was causing a problem, I found out that the real width issue was my images that were forcing the table wider that I could set it